# Computing a real integral using the Cauchy integration formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

Compute the real integral:

$$\int_0^{2{\pi}} \frac{dx}{2+\sin(x)}.$$

The idea here is to convert this real integral into a complex integral, and then solve it using the Cauchy integration form.

Here is what I have thus far:

Consider that $ \sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i} $.

Thus,

$$\int_0^{2{\pi}} \frac{dx}{2+\sin(x)}=\int_0^{2{\pi}}\frac{dx}{2+\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}}= \int_0^{2{\pi}}\frac{dx}{2+\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}}\cdot\frac{2ie^{ix}}{2ie^{ix}}=\int_0^{2{\pi}}\frac{2ie^{ix}}{(e^{ix})^2+4ie^{ix}-1}dx.$$

If we let $z=e^{ix}$, where $dz=ie^{ix}$, the integral becomes:

$$\int_c\frac{2}{z^2+4iz-1}dz$$

I found that the roots of the denominator are $z=-i(2+\sqrt{3})$, and $z=i(\sqrt{3}-2)$. We can again rewrite the integral as:

$$2 \int_c\frac{\frac{1}{(z+(2i+\sqrt{3}i)}}{(z-(-2i+\sqrt{3}i)}dz.$$

At this point I am confused as to how I would actually going about applying the cauchy integration formula... Hopefully I've done my math properly thus far. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I may have figured something out after some more reading,

I think it is the case that I should use $\vert z \vert =1 $ as my disk. Plus I may have the formula worked out, so I think everything becomes

$$2 \int_{\vert z \vert =1}\frac{\frac{1}{(z+(2i+\sqrt{3}i)}}{(z-(-2i+\sqrt{3}i)}dz=4\pi i \cdot \frac{1}{i(\sqrt 3 -2)+i(\sqrt3 + 2)} = \frac{4\pi}{\sqrt 3}$$

Still not positive on this, but seems closer.

Looks like I missed a $2$ in my denominator on the last step... should read:

$$\frac{4\pi}{2\sqrt 3}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt 3}$$

Comment: It seems you chose the wrong pole: $-(2+\sqrt 3)i$ is outside the unit circle.

Comment: I may be confused, but I don't think I'm choosing a pole. I'm finding roots so that I can rewrite the function in the form of $\frac{f(z)}{z-a}$.

Comment: Exactly! You had two choices for your $a$, but you picked the wrong one, as you have to pick the one inside the unit circle.

Comment: AH! Makes sense.

Comment: I think that is it then, I just flipped my two roots.

Comment: So $a$ is a pole? I may have a misunderstanding as to what a pole actually is.

Comment: A pole is an https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_singularity when the limit of the function is $\infty$. When you have a rational function, the zeros of the denominator are poles for the function. When you have transcendental functions you can find the Laurent development of it around a point to state if it is a pole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered the question in my edits of the original question. The last stipulation is that the Cauchy integration formula can be applied in this manner because $$f(z)= \frac{1}{(z+(2i+\sqrt{3}i))},$$ is holomorphic on the unit disc.